# What happen to files in staging area after commit?

Tags: git, indexing, staging

Someone said that files in staging area will be clear after commit.

Someone said that files in staging area will not be cleared after commit.

Which one is correct?

---

**Update**: Thanks for the responses.

Based on my understandings, staging area is the index.

I use ***"git ls-files --stage"*** command to show the file listed in the index.

- Before adding file to staging area with add command, it is empty.
- After adding file to staging area (before commit), it show the file name.
- After commit, it still show the filename. I think it is still listed in the index.

Is this the correct way to do it?

---

I want to know it because I want to understand *"git reset --mixed"* command.

Comment: The whole point of a commit is to record the state of the staging area.   Both are trivially correct because there are no files in the staging area.  The staging area only records meta-data.

Answer (score 1):

> Someone said that files in staging area will be clear after commit.
> Someone said that files in staging area will not be cleared after
> commit.
> Which one is correct?

The second is more correct. If you say `git commit` plain and simple, the files in the staging area will match the files in the commit you just made — because that's what the staging area *is*, namely, the place where you specify what will go into the next commit. Which, in effect, by and large, more or less, will be *all the files in your project.* That's what a commit is: a snapshot of (roughly) the entire state of the project.

It *looks* like the staging area is empty, maybe, because `git status` doesn't list any files ready to be committed. But that's merely because you just *did* commit them, so there are no *differences* between the stage and the last commit. As you have already found, you can readily explore what's in the staging area with `ls-files` and prove it.

> I want to know it because I want to understand "git reset --mixed" command.

Well, I don't see how it will help with that, but okay.